# jQuery DatePicker automatically adds a ":" at the end of the selected date

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-applications

### Update: I don't want to manually specify the date format as the different culture may have different date format. As a result, if I specify the dateFormat the Australian standard, and users are in China , it may also cause problems.So what I want is how to automatically pick up the dateFormat relating to the local culture with jQuery.

I found an interesting issue on jQuery DatePicker.

when I run my web application on my machine, everything goes well, no issues at all.
But after I configured it on the web server, then the value of selected date from the jQuery DatePicker
will add automatically a " :" (a white space and a colon) at the end.

E.g. the actual date picked is 08/23/2012, the tbDate.Vale will be 08/23/2012 :

I can be easily fixed buy trim() and substring() methods, but if I go this way I have to change all code which I applied the DatePicker and then re-compile the code then upload the dll to server.

So I want to ask 2 questions:
1. Why does this happen?
2. How to fix it in a general and global way? (like add some configure in Web.config file)

I am waiting for your answers.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the jQuery reference

```
  <script src="Resource/JS/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Resource/css/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Resource/JS/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The function to pop-up DatePicker:

```
        function showDatePicker(datepicker) {
            var id = "#" + datepicker;
            $(function () {
                $(id).datepicker();
            });
        }

    </script>
```

The input component:

```
<input id="tbActionDate" type="text" runat="server"  class="datePickerControl" clientidmode="Static"  onclick="showDatePicker('tbActionDate');" />
```

Comment: Post your code please........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You control the formatting of the date string like this:

```
var DatePicker = $('#DatePicker_TextBox').datepicker();

DatePicker.datepicker('option',
{
   dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
   numberOfMonths: [1, 2],
   showWeek: 'true' 
});
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for your advice, but I don't want to specify the date format as different culture may have different date format. Any other idea?

Comment: Hello.  You don't have to hard code it, you could use a global variable to set the string and then use the variable when you create datepickers.  Or you could try this: https://github.com/jquery/globalize

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the format of the date - check that you are not asking it to add the ":".

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
```

There is more information on this in the [jQuery UI DatePicker documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Comment: Hi Sohnee, I don't want to manually specify the date format as the different culture may have different date format. So I want a way which can automatically pick up the local culture date format.

Comment: @Franva putting the culture aside for now, does setting the `dateFormat` solve the problem with the ":"?

Comment: ,Thank you for your suggestion, but if I do it in this way, then I have to go through all places where I used the DatePicker, which is not the solution that I'm looking for.

Comment: @Franva the idea behind this was to ascertain whether or not this even solved your problem. Never mind.