# jQuery DatePicker issue: string was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Exception is :

Operation failed String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Here is the jQuery reference

```
  <script src="Resource/JS/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Resource/css/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Resource/JS/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The function to pop-up DatePicker:

```
        function showDatePicker(datepicker) {
            var id = "#" + datepicker;
            $(function () {
                $(id).datepicker();
            });
        }

    </script>
```

The input component:

```
<input id="tbActionDate" type="text" runat="server"  class="datePickerControl" clientidmode="Static"  onclick="showDatePicker('tbActionDate');" />
```

And I have tried to do it in this way: $(id).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "mm/dd/yy");
It doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery DatePicker automatically adds a ":" at the end of the selected date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006786/jquery-datepicker-automatically-adds-a-at-the-end-of-the-selected-date)

Comment: @pimvdb thx, I've changed the content and title. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It wasn't because of the jQuery DatePicker, but the Convert.ToDateTime() in .NET cannot handle the date format (mm/dd/yyyy).

So I wrote my own method to convert it to the right object of DateTime.

Do you guys have any solutions to convert this date format to an object of DateTime in C#?

I've tried to use the CultureInfo to get the local culture object and used it to be a parameter in the Convert.ToDateTime() method,  but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use latest version of jQuery UI datepicker which has the following useful functions

- http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate
- http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate

Comment: not helpful. I did check all of them. Not work for me. Thx anyway.